# How to keep track of range slider in constant time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is what I have to represent the text box and the slider:

```
          <input id="rangeInputM" type="range" min="-10" max="10" oninput="m1.value=rangeInputM.value" />
          <input id="m1" type="number" value="1" min="-200" max="200" oninput="rangeInputM.value=m1.value" />
```

I know how to keep track of user input into the text box:

```
   $("#m1").keyup(function(){
    
    var m1,b1 = 0;

    m1 = parseFloat($("#m1").val());
    b1 = parseFloat($("#b1").val());

   
    var myGraph = new Graph({
     canvasId: 'Graph',
     minX: -10,
     minY: -10,
     maxX: 10,
     maxY: 10,
     unitsPerTick: 1
    });      
    
    myGraph.drawLine(m1, b1, 'blue', 3);
  });
```

But I do not know how to do the same thing to the range slider to keep track of that value.
This link is if you want to test the entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/csCoder/eLxfrn10/9/

Comment: Use the `change` method instead: `$("#m1, #b1, #rangeInputM, #rangeInputB").change(function(){ ... }`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! Just out of curiosity, how would I change my code so that it would change AS I am dragging the slider, instead of only changing after I LET GO of the slider?

Comment: In that case use `$("#m1, #b1, #rangeInputM, #rangeInputB").on("input", function(){ ... }` instead.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! So I guess I use change to only update at the end and I use on, to continuously update. Appreciate it!